# Should the vendor folder be in source control?

Tags: php, composer-php

For instance, files like

```
/vendor/composer/classLoader.php
/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

On a project I'm on these are checked in. I wasn't sure whether that's good practice or not, as I remember reading Laravel recommends `/vendor` to be in `.gitignore`.

Comment: What you want to keep in source control is your composer.json file, not the files that composer loads based on composer.json

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the `vendor` directory should be excluded, and never manually touched. A `composer update` / `composer install` will generate the class loader when you install your dependencies.

Answer (score 13):

**No**, your vendor folder is not part of your source code, and shouldn't be 
checked in in your git repository.

A good workflow would be :

- check in your composer.json
- whenever you want to upgrade your dependencies:

  - run `composer update` on your **local repository**
  - check in the changed `composer.lock`
  - Deploy and run `composer install` on your **production repository**

### Why should you also check in composer.lock :

Your `composer.json` defines the acceptable versions of your dependencies that will be used when running `composer update`.

The problem that comes in when using only `composer.json` is to have reproducible builds (eg exactly the same versions of your dependencies in all your environments). That is why, when you run composer install, if there is a `composer.lock` file, composer will instead load the exact same dependencies as the ones written in the composer.lock file. Your `composer.lock` file is updated whenever you run `composer update`.

Comment: Big +1 for the details on composer.lock.